# What is the difference betweeen: aws-sdk/clients/appsync and aws-appsync?

Tags: aws-appsync

Can anyone please tell me what is the difference between:

`aws-sdk/clients/appsync`, and `aws-appsync`

According to the doc, `aws-sdk/clients/appsync` is used because just including `aws-sdk` is too large when we just need appsync, we use `aws-sdk/clients/appsync`.

However, `aws-appsync` seems also doing the same thing. When I create a client using `aws-sdk/clients/appsync`, there is no `hydrated()` function while `aws-appsync` has.

So

- Why can't we simplify everything by just using `aws-sdk/clients/<any_aws_package>` and break everything that did not use it?
- What is the point of separating something that is similar?

Thank you very much in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> difference between: aws-sdk/clients/appsync, and aws-appsync

`GraphQL` originated at Facebook and the React/React Native apps used `react-apollo` to talk to the GraphQL based APIs.

`AWS AppSync` is the AWS offering for `GraphQL`. `aws-sdk/clients/appsync` is the JS SDK to invoke various `AppSync` management/control APIs (like create GraphQL API,  create data source etc). Not sure if they also provided apis to consume the GraphQL based api.

`aws-appsync` is the way to consume `AppSync` backed GraphQL APIs. It plays well with `react-apollo` which is now moved to `apollo-client`.

There is another high level JS library from AWS [Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/js), which is used to consume `AppSync` backed GraphQL APIs.

> aws-sdk/clients/appsync is used because just including aws-sdk is too
> large

The initial release of the `aws-sdk` (Github repo [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js)) contained the clients for all the AWS services and more. You need to install `aws-sdk` and you can talk to pretty much all the AWS services by initialising the clients for them. Obvisously it was not so good in terms of packaging JS bundles, the library was also not very modular.

Now the latest version V3 (rewritten using TypeScript) which is GA now, moves the clients to individual npm packages i.e. you need to only install the client you need e.g. `npm i @aws-sdk/client-appsync` instead of `npm i aws-sdk`. Learn more about it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/modular-packages-in-aws-sdk-for-javascript/). If you are getting started use the `V3` packages.

> Why can't we simplify everything by just using
> aws-sdk/clients/<any_aws_package> and break everything that did not
> use it?

It is the case with the [V3 JS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3).

> What is the point of separating something that is similar?

They are not similar. One is used to consume the GraphQL based APIs (provided by AppSync) and the other is to manage AppSync itself. The V3 packages follow this very strictly while the earlier versions may have some utility code/ high level abstractions along with the core AWS apis.

Comment: now we have aws-sdk hell.

Comment: I'm am in confusion for few days already. But this is AWS, we understand.